Getting element click intercepted: Element ...............................is not clickable at point (413, 146)
I am trying to click a radio button on the UI ,I have already tried waiting for the element ,javascript executor ,tried writing robust xpath but no luck yet
Only thing unusual I could see while inspecting the element is the element is inside the div tag with class as class="usaa-pageTransition-animationHandler"
While navigating to the page the page loads from right to left.
<div class="usaa-pageTransition-animationHandler" style="transition: min-height 1400ms; opacity: 1; min-height: 537px;"><div tabindex="-1" class="usaa-pageTransition-focusable"></div><div><div class="usaa-pageTransition-baseTransition usaa-pageTransition-baseTransition-enter-done"><div class="page-content form-center" data-testid="page-content">

I have tried using fluent wait ,waituntil ,javascript executor ,tried thread.sleep as well
I have already checked the element is not inside an iframe.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Perhaps it is caused by another web element covered the radio button when you try to click it. You can add a screenshot before click it. to confirm it is covered by other element or not.
